# Print or save output of tf.keras model, paired with inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, file-io

```py
def locations_model(...):
    input_shape = image_shape + (3,)
    base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(...)                                                                base_model.trainable = False 
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(...)  
... ...     
    outputs = tfl.Dense(5, activation = "softmax")(x)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
 
    return model
```

The code above is just to show inputs and outputs in a tf.keras model that classifies input images into 5 categories.
How can I save the output category ("y_pred") for every input image?

The simple statement
`ypreds = model(inputs)`
or `ypreds = model.predict(inputs)` produces a set of 5-element arrays that add to 1, i.e., probabilities.
The question therefore is how to output the predicted categories, which in this case are integers: 0-4, instead of the probabilities.
Update: this was answer by Apostolova for the question "Get class labels from Keras functional model" by Lodzz, as
test_probas = model.predict(test_data)
test_classes = probas.argmax(axis = -1)

Comment: In order to format code, you have to put three backticks (```) at the start and the end of the code. Ensure that you put the backticks at an empty line, not on a line that does already contain code. Additionally, you can add a language identifier after the first three backticks.

Comment: As I wrote in the edited question, Emilia Apostolova has it all figured out.  The code is ```probas = model(x_in); x_classes = probas.argmax( axis = - 1)```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the confirmation **@EduardoriosChicago**. I am mentioning your answer here for the benefit of the community.

> The code is
>
> ```
> probas = model(x_in); 
> x_classes = probas.argmax( axis = - 1)
> ```